# GMarks is not displaying my bookmarks toolbar

Tags: browser-addons, firefox

I have GMarks set up and "Bookmarks Toolbar" as the toolbar label but my toolbar is empty. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

Is that the precise spelling and capitalization of the label you've tagged your bookmarks with? I've just had a quick play and my bookmarks only appear on the toolbar if the label is spelled precisely the same. And obviously there need to be bookmarks tagged with that label!

Comment: Yup, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Could you perhaps give us a bit more detail on how you have GMarks configured?

Answer (score 0):

when I right click the original "Bookmarks Toolbar" under firefox Bookmarks, I see that the name is actually "Bookmarks Menu". So how should I label it in Gmark - "Bookmarks Toolbar" or "Bookmarks Menu" or else ?

Comment: Hey numidaf, i'm sure many people would love to answer your question if it was asked in it's own separate question (http://superuser.com/questions/ask)!